# Как добавить ActivityTwo в AndroidManifest (Android Studio)

Tags: android, java

1001 пример добавления в Eclipse, ни одного в Android Studio. Дело в том что в Eclipse добавляется кнопками, а в AS кодом. Сам попробовал добавить, не вышло.

*Обновление*

Манифест

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.buttons.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

 <activity android:name="com.example.buttons.app.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" > <intent-filter>

 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity 
            android:name=".ActivityTwo" 
            android:label="ActivityTwo">
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Пробовал..

Comment: и есть ошибки? или может ты не правильно вызываешь его?

Comment: Нет, заработало, спасибо =)

Answer (score 1):

Подробно тут: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html